# How to change Date and Time format in Java

Tags: java, date, time

i know this is a simple question but what date and time format should i use to show this output.

```
2019-02-06T3:26:40+08:00
```

I’m using java.time.
I use `LocalDateTime` but it only outputs 2020-10-06T16:40:04 and didn’t have the +08:00.

I only use this:

```
LocalDateTime myObj = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(myObj);
```

I don’t know how to format like the example above.

Comment: What date and time API are you using? `java.util` or `java.time` or anything else?

Comment: im using java.time

Comment: Then prepare a `DateTimeFormatter`... What class is holding your datetime value? An `OffsetDateTime` or a `ZonedDateTime`? Please show some lines of code, for example those that initialize the object.

Comment: i use LocalDateTime but it only output 2020-10-06T16:40:04. and didnt have the +08:00

Comment: That's because a `LocalDateTime` does not hold information about a zone or an offset. Again, please show the initialization code along with the line(s) you tried for formatted output.

Comment: i only use this

Comment: LocalDateTime myObj = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(myObj);

Comment: i dont know how to format like the example above

Comment: @paroxysm04 Thank you for providing a lot of good extra information. It’s always better to do that in the question itself than in comments (only this time I pasted it in there for you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
// take the current time at a specific offset from UTC
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(8));
// define an output pattern
String pattern = "uuu-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ssxxx";
// and print some result using a formatter with the pattern defined
System.out.println("Formatted with pattern "
                   + pattern 
                   + ": " 
                   + offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)));
```

will output something similar to this line (time may/will differ, at least):

```
Formatted with pattern uuu-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ssxxx: 2020-10-06T17:02:49+08:00
```

---

**Problem with your code**:

1. Your code example was given in a comment, not in the question
   (this is **not a functional problem related to Java** but still a problem here, you can edit that)
2. You are currently using a `LocalDateTime`, which does not hold any information about an offset or a time zone
3. You are not defining a desired output pattern but (implicitly) invoking the `toString()` method of the `LocalDateTime` by just printing the instance in the following code (the one from your comment):

```java
LocalDateTime myObj = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(myObj);
```

outputs a `String` like `2020-10-06T16:40:04` without the desired `+08:00`.

You can create an `OffsetDateTime` using an instance of `LocalDateTime` and a desired `ZoneOffset`, like

```java
LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now();
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(localNow, ZoneOffset.ofHours(8));
System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
```

which also uses a predefined output pattern, which slightly differs from your desired one (fractions-of-second is displayed between seconds and the offset).

**But please note that this approach may return an incorrect point in time under certain circumstances (see the comment by @OleV.V. below this answer).**

If you are sure every system that code is running on has and will always have a time zone setting with an offset of `+08:00`, you can use `OffsetDateTime.now()` without adding a `ZoneOffset` explicitly or use the system default exlicitly by `OffsetDateTime nowExplicitSystemOffset = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());`.

I recommend having a look at [Trail: Date Time (The Java Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: Good answer! For future visitors: An alternative of `OffsetDateTime.of(localNow, ZoneOffset.ofHours(8))` can be `localNow.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(8))`. Use whichever feels natural to you.

Comment: There’s good information here. `LocalDateTime.now()` without argument followed by `OffsetDateTime.of(localNow, ZoneOffset.ofHours(8))` is prohibitively dangerous. If the code happens to run on a JVM with a time zone setting that doesn’t agree with the expected offset of +08:00, you will get a wrong point in time without any sign that it is wrong. Instead use for example `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(8))`.

Comment: @OleV.V. That's a very interesting point (which I didn't consider before).

Answer (score 3):

### OffsetDateTime

Use `OffsetDateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`:

```
    OffsetDateTime myObj = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(myObj);
```

I ran this just now in Asia/Hong_Kong time zone. The output was:

> 2020-10-07T03:25:03.254761+08:00

The format you asked for is ISO 8601. The classes of java,time generally print ISO 8601 format from their `toString` methods. A `LocalDateTime` object doesn’t include any offset or time zone. An `OffsetDateTime`, as the name says, does include a UTC offset such as `+08:00` and therefore also prints it from `toString()`.

It is not strictly necessary to pass `ZoneId.systemDefault()` as argument to `now()`. You will get the same result if you leave it out. Since the current time is time zone dependent, I always prefer to make it explicit which time zone I am using, so I and the reader both know that I have made a conscious choice.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Yet another good answer! The `Wikipedia` link is very informative and everyone aiming to obtain a good understanding of date-time should study it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CurrentDateTimeExample2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(java.time.Clock.systemUTC().instant()); 
    }
}
```

Example output:

> 2020-10-07T20:50:11.758582Z

Comment: It’s halfway correct. It gives output like `2020-10-06T17:33:34.597702Z`, which is ISO 8601 format like the format asked for. My guess is that the OP also wants the offset of `+08:00` as given in the example in the question.